# How to control the path of connectors in a UML diagram

Tags: vba, uml, visio

I am drawing a UML diagram in visio programmatically in which i am using a dynamic connector to connect shapes.But there are situations when the connector makes its way through the shape rather passing through the page(i.e. connector makes its route from source to destination shape through another shape lying in between source and destination),I want that connector should make its way through page only.Pls suggest how to make this possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to translate from C#, but this is how I'm doing it:

```
/// <summary>Attaches two Visio shapes to each other with the specified connector object.</summary>
/// <param name="shape1">Visio shape to connect from.</param>
/// <param name="shape2">Visio shape to connect to.</param>
/// <param name="connector">Visio line shape that will connect shape1 to shape2.</param>
/// <param name="straight">Whether this connector should be a straight line</param>
[CLSCompliant(false)]
protected static void ConnectShapes(
    Visio.Shape shape1,
    Visio.Shape shape2,
    Visio.Shape connector,
    bool straight = false)
    {
        try
        {
            // get the cell from the source side of the connector
            Visio.Cell beginXCell = connector.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject, (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXForm1D, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.vis1DBeginX];

            // glue the source side of the connector to the first shape
            beginXCell.GlueTo(shape1.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject, (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visXFormPinX]);

            // get the cell from the destination side of the connector
            Visio.Cell endXCell = connector.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject, (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXForm1D, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.vis1DEndX];

            // glue the destination side of the connector to the second shape
            endXCell.GlueTo(shape2.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject, (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visXFormPinX]);

            if (straight)
            {
                connector.CellsU["ConLineRouteExt"].ResultIUForce = (double)Visio.VisCellVals.visLORouteExtStraight;
                connector.CellsU["ShapeRouteStyle"].ResultIUForce = (double)Visio.VisCellVals.visLORouteCenterToCenter;
            }
            else
            {
                // THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR
                connector.CellsU["ConLineRouteExt"].ResultIUForce = (double)Visio.VisCellVals.visLORouteExtNURBS;
                connector.CellsU["ShapeRouteStyle"].ResultIUForce = (double)Visio.VisCellVals.visLORouteRightAngle;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
```